# Graphviz: Decrease the space between label and node boundary

Tags: graphviz

By default there is a lot of space between the text of the label and the boundary of the node. How to reduce that spacing? This would usually be called padding but pad means something else for the graphviz - the overall spacing between the graph and the boundary of the figure. What is the name of the attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for margin, but be also aware of height and width which actually specify min-height and min-width

example

```
digraph G {
 node[shape=rect]
 A
 "B0123456789\n0\n1"
 "C0123456789\n0\n1"[margin=0]
}
```

[image]